# Properties of the commutator subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $f:G\to H$ be a homomorphism of groups.

Is it true that $G/[G,G]\cong f(G)/[f(G),f(G)]$, where $[,]$ denotes the commutator subgroup?

Comment: $H$ could be trivial.

Comment: To expand @DerekHolt's comment (correct me if I'm wrong): If $H$ is trivial, then the proposed homomorphism $f$ maps everything to the identity of $H$, meaning $f(G) = \{e_H\}$ (because $H$ has no other elements). Since $G$ is arbitrary, its abelianization $G/[G,G]$ need not be trivial, but the abelianization of $f(G)$ clearly is, so they're not isomorphic

Answer (score 2):

No, let $G=\Bbb Z$ and $H=D_8$ with $f(x)=e$ Then we have 
$$\Bbb Z/[\Bbb Z,\Bbb Z]=\Bbb Z/e=\Bbb Z$$
but 
$$f(\Bbb Z)=e$$
and as such
$$e/[e,e]=e$$
Which are clearly not isomorphic.